# Want to make a drive to be writable

Tags: 14.04

I have a drive partition. I can't make two drives to be writable. I forgot the command to make it writable.

[image: want to make these 2 drives to be writable]

I have given something like this.

```
sudo mount ntfs rw /dev/sda5
```

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test it:

> sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda5

Comment: sorry.. it's not working... i get message as mount: /dev/sda5 not mounted or bad option

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.

Comment: @BhavinShah Is it this drive common between Linux and another os is for example windows?

Comment: yes.. these drives are common

Comment: @BhavinShah Ok ,so in your windows and then restart it by this: press ctrl+r and write them "shutdown -r" and enter

Comment: @BhavinShah If it worked  please flag my answer accept

Comment: @BhavinShah -  :)